# convert json string to hashmap in java using collector

Tags: java, dictionary, serialization

i am having string in form of `[{"roll":1,"name":"Alok"},{"roll":2,"name":"Ayush kumar"}]`  want to convert it in hashmap. I have tried `HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) Arrays.asList(emp.split(",")).stream().map(s -> s.split(":")).collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e[0], e -> e[1]));`
  But getting error `Duplicate key "Ayush kumar"}] with root cause`

Comment: Consider using a JSON-parser instead of the "regex"-stuff you're trying now. Even if you make this work, you'll probably be happier at a later point.

Comment: @Henrik i will user JSON parser. If u suggest short example

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial

Comment: @Henrik Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using [Jackson](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial), your JSON can be parsed like this:

```
String input = "[{\"roll\":1,\"name\":\"Alok\"},{\"roll\":2,\"name\":\"Ayush kumar\"}]";

ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
List<Map<String, String>> list = om.readValue(input, List.class);
```

Note that your JSON is actually a list of objects (ie. maps), so you need to deserialize to a `List` instance. Go through the list and join the maps to get a single map.